# Child progress bar not disappearing with -Completed flag

Tags: powershell

I have:

```
for($i = 0; $i -lt 10; $i++)
{
    for($k = 0; $k -lt 10; $k++)
    {
        Write-Progress -Activity "Main" -Id 1 -CurrentOperation "Parenting" -PercentComplete (($i / 10) * 100)
        Write-Progress -Activity "Child" -Id 2 -ParentId 1 -CurrentOperation "Childing" -PercentComplete (($k / 10) * 100)

        Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100        
    }

    Write-Progress -Activity "Child" -Id 2 -Completed

    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
}

Write-Progress -Activity "Main" -Id 1 -Completed

#Rest of script
Read-Host Lalalal:
```

Problem is that when `#rest of script` part of code is executed the child ProgressBar never disappears. Also Child bar does not disappear after each child progress loop. How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I found problem.
I need to specify -ParentId in Write-Progress with -Completed switch.